# Synchronize Three Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Was asked this question in an interview , tried to solve it ... but not successful.
I thought of using CyclicBarrier

There are three threads T1 prints 1,4,7... T2 prints 2,5,8... and T3 prints 3,6,9 …. How do you synchronize these three to print sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....

I tried writing & running the following code

```
public class CyclicBarrierTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CyclicBarrier cBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(3);
        new Thread(new ThreadOne(cBarrier,1,10,"One")).start();
        new Thread(new ThreadOne(cBarrier,2,10,"Two")).start();
        new Thread(new ThreadOne(cBarrier,3,10,"Three")).start();
    }
}

class ThreadOne implements Runnable {
    private CyclicBarrier cb;
    private String name;
    private int startCounter;
    private int numOfPrints;

    public ThreadOne(CyclicBarrier cb, int startCounter,int numOfPrints,String name) {
        this.cb = cb;
        this.startCounter=startCounter;
        this.numOfPrints=numOfPrints;
        this.name=name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int counter=0;counter<numOfPrints;counter++)
        {
            try {
            // System.out.println(">>"+name+"<< "+cb.await());
            cb.await();
            System.out.println("["+name+"] "+startCounter);
            cb.await();
            //System.out.println("<<"+name+">> "+cb.await());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        startCounter+=3;
        }
    }

}
```

output

```
[Three] 3
[One] 1
[Two] 2
[One] 4
[Two] 5
[Three] 6
[Two] 8
[One] 7
[Three] 9
[One] 10
[Two] 11
[Three] 12
[Two] 14
[One] 13
[Three] 15
[One] 16
[Two] 17
[Three] 18
[Two] 20
[One] 19
[Three] 21
[One] 22
[Two] 23
[Three] 24
[Two] 26
[One] 25
[Three] 27
[One] 28
[Two] 29
[Three] 30
```

Can anyone help me with correct ans ?

Similar Ques
[Thread Synchronization - Synchronizing three threads to print 012012012012..... not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912157/thread-synchronization-synchronizing-three-threads-to-print-012012012012)

Comment: What about sharing the current number you're trying to print with an AtomicInteger passed to the constructor. If this is a number the current thread can't print, it just blocks on the barrier, again?

Comment: This question is already answered : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41671224/3233586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others already mentioned, CyclicBarrier is not exactly the best tool for the task.

I also share the opinion that the solution is to chain the threads and let always one thread set the go for the next one.

Here goes an implementation using Semaphore:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException; 
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class PrintNumbersWithSemaphore implements Runnable {

private final Semaphore previous;

private final Semaphore next;

private final int[] numbers;

public PrintNumbersWithSemaphore(Semaphore previous, Semaphore next, int[] numbers) {
    this.previous = previous;
    this.next = next;
    this.numbers = numbers;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        wait4Green();

        System.out.println(numbers[i]);

        switchGreen4Next();
    }
}

private void switchGreen4Next() {
        next.release();
}

private void wait4Green() {
    try {
        previous.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

static public void main(String argv[]) throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
    Semaphore sem1 = new Semaphore(1);
    Semaphore sem2 = new Semaphore(1);
    Semaphore sem3 = new Semaphore(1);
    sem1.acquire();
    sem2.acquire();
    sem3.acquire();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new PrintNumbersWithSemaphore(sem3, sem1, new int[] { 1, 4, 7 }));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new PrintNumbersWithSemaphore(sem1, sem2, new int[] { 2, 5, 8 }));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new PrintNumbersWithSemaphore(sem2, sem3, new int[] { 3, 6, 9 }));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    sem3.release();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}

}
```

Here goes another one, in my opinion quite cumbersome implementation using CyclicBarrier:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException; 
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class PrintNumbersWithCyclicBarrier implements Runnable {

private final CyclicBarrier previous;

private final CyclicBarrier next;

private final int[] numbers;

public PrintNumbersWithCyclicBarrier(CyclicBarrier previous, CyclicBarrier next, int[] numbers) {
    this.previous = previous;
    this.next = next;
    this.numbers = numbers;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        wait4Green();

        System.out.println(numbers[i]);

        switchRed4Myself();

        switchGreen4Next();
    }
}

private void switchGreen4Next() {
    try {
        next.await();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void switchRed4Myself() {
    previous.reset();
}

private void wait4Green() {
    try {
        previous.await();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

static public void main(String argv[]) throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
    CyclicBarrier cb1 = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    CyclicBarrier cb2 = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    CyclicBarrier cb3 = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new PrintNumbersWithCyclicBarrier(cb3, cb1, new int[] { 1, 4, 7 }));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new PrintNumbersWithCyclicBarrier(cb1, cb2, new int[] { 2, 5, 8 }));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new PrintNumbersWithCyclicBarrier(cb2, cb3, new int[] { 3, 6, 9 }));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    cb3.await();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Michael , thanks for your Ans ... it was no requirement to use CyclicBarrier ... BTW the output of PrintNumbersWithCyclicBarrier is correct ... BUT PrintNumbersWithSemaphore incorrectly prints ... 2,3,1,4,7,6,5,8,9 or 1,4,,2,5,8,3,6,7,9 .... So Whats the best solution

Comment: Hi Lav, thanks for your feedback. There was a bug in the Semaphore version, I corrected it. The three Semaphore constructors needs an argument of 1 instead of 2. This happened as I ported the code from Semaphore to CyclicBarier and then back again (the argument of two slipped in). The functioning of both versions is as described by John Vint, each Thread waiting until it gets green to print his number and after that setting the go for the next Thread, with Thread3 chained to Thread1. For this kind of synchronisation is Semaphore better choice then CyclicBarrier.

Comment: CyclicBarrier is used when multiple threads need to wait for each thread in the given group to reach some point of execution. Therefore the CyclicBarrier version is more like a workaround and the Semaphore version is more correct. It is also possible that if I bent the assingment definition still a little further, I might get yet better version.

Comment: OK, I gave my try on the yet better version while bending the assignment yet a bit more, but did not manage it. At the moment I do not get it better then the Semaphore version.

Answer (score 2):

Was the requirement to use a **single**  `CyclicBarrier`?  My suggestion is:

1. For each ThreadOne instance assign two CyclicBarriers
2. You should create a cyclic graph such that

   `ThreadOne_1 -> ThreadOne_2 -> ThreadOne_3 -> ThreadOne_1 -> etc...`
3. To achieve (2) you would need to share the parent's `CyclicBarrier` with the child's and than the last task should share it's CB with the first Thread's child.

To answer your questions:

> Tried going through the documents , but not very clear what exactly does await() do ...

Await will suspend itself until `N` number of threads have invoked `await` on the barrier.  So if you define `new CyclicBarrier(3)` than once 3 threads invoke `await` the barrier will allow threads to continue.

> When to use reset()

You don't need to, it will auto trip the barrier once the number of threads arive

Comment: Was there a requirement to use _any_ cyclic barrier?  CyclicBarrier does not seem like the right tool to use:  It simultaneously releses _all_ of the waiting threads when the last thread arrives.

Comment: @jameslarge You're right I wouldn't use a CB either, but based on his question title, I assume at least one was required.

Comment: I have learnedto assume nothing when reading other people's code or, when trying to understand their problems.

Comment: @jameslarge Right, but the title specifically said `Synchronize Three Threads using CyclicBarrier`, so I think it's a fair assumption to make.  It was an interview question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing it which works for an arbitrary number of threads using synchronized, wait and notifyAll.
A `turn` variable controls which is the thread that has to execute. Such thread executes the task, increases `turn` (in modulo number of threads), notifeis all threads and goes to a while loop awaiting until it is its turn again.

```
public class Test2 {

    final static int LOOPS = 10;
    final static int NUM_TREADS = 3;

    static class Sequenced extends Thread {

        static int turn = 0;
        static int count = 0;
        static Object lock = new Object();
        final int order;

        public Sequenced(int order) {
            this.order = order;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    for (int n = 0; n < LOOPS; ++n) {
                        while (turn != order) {
                            lock.wait();
                        }
                        ++count;
                        System.out.println("T" + (order + 1) + " " + count);
                        turn = (turn + 1) % NUM_TREADS;
                        lock.notifyAll();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    // Nothing to do but to let the thread die.
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Sequenced[] threads = new Sequenced[NUM_TREADS];
        for (int n = 0; n < NUM_TREADS; ++n) {
            threads[n] = new Sequenced(n);
            threads[n].start();
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < NUM_TREADS; ++n) {
            threads[n].join();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As threads should be given equal weightage i.e first after second after third. The following works.

```
public class MultiThreadSynchronize {

static int index = 0;
static Object lock = new Object();

static class NumberPrinter extends Thread {
    private final int remainder;
    private final int noOfThreads;
    private int value;

    public NumberPrinter(String name, int remainder, int noOfThreads, int value) {
        super(name);
        this.remainder = remainder;
        this.noOfThreads = noOfThreads;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (index < 20) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                while ((index % noOfThreads) != remainder) {. // base condition where all threads except one waits.
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                index++;
                System.out.println(getName() + " " + value);
                value += 3;
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberPrinter numberPrinter1 = new NumberPrinter("First Thread", 0, 3, 1);
    NumberPrinter numberPrinter2 = new NumberPrinter("Second Thread", 1, 3, 2);
    NumberPrinter numberPrinter3 = new NumberPrinter("Third Thread", 2, 3, 3);
    numberPrinter1.start(); numberPrinter2.start(); numberPrinter3.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have coded one three thread application using events

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;


HANDLE firstThreadEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, true, true, NULL);
HANDLE secondThreadEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, NULL);
HANDLE thirdThreadEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, NULL);
std::atomic<int> m_int = 1;

DWORD WINAPI firstThreadFun(LPVOID lparam)
{
    while (1)
    {
        ::WaitForSingleObject(firstThreadEvent,INFINITE);
        cout << "By first thread " << m_int << std::endl;
        m_int++;
        ResetEvent(firstThreadEvent);
        SetEvent(secondThreadEvent);

    }
}
DWORD WINAPI secondThreadFun(LPVOID lparam)
{
    while (1)
    {
        ::WaitForSingleObject(secondThreadEvent, INFINITE);
        cout << "By second thread "<< m_int << std::endl;
        m_int++;
        ResetEvent(secondThreadEvent);
        SetEvent(thirdThreadEvent);

    }

}
DWORD WINAPI thirdThreadFun(LPVOID lparam)
{
    while (1)
    {
        ::WaitForSingleObject(thirdThreadEvent, INFINITE);
        cout << "By third thread " << m_int << std::endl;
        m_int++;
        ResetEvent(thirdThreadEvent);
        SetEvent(firstThreadEvent);

    }
}



int main()
{
    HANDLE hnd[3];
    hnd[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &firstThreadFun, NULL, 0, NULL);
    hnd[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &secondThreadFun, NULL, 0, NULL);
    hnd[2] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &thirdThreadFun, NULL, 0, NULL);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(3, hnd, true, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hnd[0]);
    CloseHandle(hnd[1]);
    CloseHandle(hnd[2]);
    return 0;
}
```