# java 2 Threads Printing numbers in sequence

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to print 1 to 10 in sequence using 2 threads.

Here is the code.

```
public class Multithreading implements Runnable {
    private static volatile Integer count = 1;
    private static volatile String threadId = "1";

    Object object = new Object();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (count <= 10) {
                synchronized (object) {
                    if(!Thread.currentThread().getName().equals(threadId)) {
                        object.wait();
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+ count);
                        count++;
                        if(threadId.equals("1"))
                            threadId = "2";
                        else threadId = "1";
                        object.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Multithreading t1m = new Multithreading();
        Multithreading t2m = new Multithreading();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(t1m);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(t2m);

        t1.setName("1");
        t2.setName("2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

But both threads are going to wait after printing 1st thread prints 1.

I'm trying to implement this [3 Threads Printing numbers in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964133/3-threads-printing-numbers-in-sequence) solution for two threads without a nested inner class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `object` variable is a *member* variable. Each instance of your `Multithreading` class is creating, synchronizing on, waiting for, and notifying its own distinct `object`. Maybe you meant for `object` to be a `static` variable?

---

**Edit:**

In the [question you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30964133/801894), the `monitor` variable is a member variable—just like your `object`—but the code creates only one instance of the class in which `monitor` appears. All the threads share the same `monitor`. The same is true of the `object` variable in [the most highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45168192/801894) to that question. All the threads share the same `object` in that answer.

The way in which you got rid of the inner class from those examples causes each thread to have its own, separate `object`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Making the `object` variable static solves my issue.